# Derivations of important algebras?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

After knowing the importance of studying derivations of an algebras([Why we wonder to know all derivations of an algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382027/why-we-wonder-to-know-all-derivations-of-an-algebra)), this problem naturally raised "what is the space of all derivations of important algebras like algebra of matrices, cliford algebra, exterior algebra and C* algebras?"
has anybody studied on this problem? In graded cases we have the notion of super and graded derivations.
does this kinds of derivations for famous algebras obtained?
If so, I want to be familiar with references with geometrical looking.

any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are many classes of algebras for which derivations have been studied.

Generally, if $A$ is an algebra and $a\in A$, the map $\delta_a:x\in A\mapsto ax-xa\in A$ is a derivation, which we call the *inner derivation* corresponding to $a$, and a somewhat boring one — for its existence does not tell us anything about the algebra. So usually what we do is consider the vector space $\def\Der{\operatorname{Der}}\Der(A)$ of all derivations, and its subspace $\def\InnDer{\operatorname{InnDer}}\InnDer(A)=\{\delta_a:a\in A\}$ and consider the quotient $\Der(A)/\InnDer(A)$ which, in a sense, tells us how many *interesting* derivations there are. We call $\Der(A)/\InnDer(AA)$ the vector space of *outer derivations* (even though its elements are not really derivations but classes of derivations) and write it $\def\OutDer{\operatorname{OutDer}}\OutDer(A)$.

The vector space $\OutDer(A)$ is an important invariant of $A$, and in fact it coincides with the so called first Hochschild cohomology group $HH^1(A)$ of $A$, which shows up all over the place.

If you want examples:

- If $A=M_n(k)$ is the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices over the ground field, then $HH^1(A)=0$. This means, precisey, that every derivation of $A$ is an inner derivation.
- If $L$ is a field extension of $k$ which is separable, then $HH^1(L)=0$ again. If the extension is nott separable, then the resul depends very much on what extension it is exactly.
- If $A$ is the Weyl algebra, that is, the algebra of differential operators (on the line, say) witth polynomial coefficients, then $HH^1(A)=0$. This is a famous result of Dixmier.
- If $A$ is an exterior algebra $\Lambda V$ on a vector space $V$, then on can easily compute $HH^1(A)$ but I do not recall the result.
- And so on and on.

(My examples maybe make it seem like $HH^1$ is always zero, but it is certainly not!)

Comment: Likewise, lots of work has been put in computing $HH^1$ for $C^*$-algebras. You should google a bit. «Hochschild cohomology» is the key keyword.

Comment: For the second bullet point, don't we require $L/k$ to be algebraic? I mean $\mathbb Q(t)$ posesses nontrivial $\mathbb Q$-linear derivations, right? (Sorry if I'm making a stupid mistake here!)